# Android - Failed to connect with google play service

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I want to get current location of user by using play service api. But always its calling `onConnectionFailed()` method. I have added **google-services.json** file with SHA-1 key. But its showing the Toast message written in onConnectionFailed() method.  How can i fix it?

Here is my code -

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        //setup GoogleApiClient
        setupGoogleApiClient();

    }

    }
    }

    //setup GoogleApiClient object
    private void setupGoogleApiClient() {
        // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected with google play service",        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection suspended with google play service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to connect with google play service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Added the code @NK mewara

Comment: You should debug it yourself and see what particular `ConnectionResult` have come.

Comment: Its showing Connection failed always. which i wrote on onConnectionFailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing play service version in your gradle file, 
if you are using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

try with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.x.x'
```

and other combination.

> **Note:-**  replace "x" with suitable values

Comment: I am using '10.0.1'. Whats wrong with it? Can you please explain me?

Comment: I just updated google play service now. but still same error.

Comment: check permissions are added, meta-data tag in android menifest and turn on gps from your mobiles setting, still if you face issue, kindly send me the URL which you are referring

Comment: I added necessary permissions and meta data. but not working. Can you please refer me a useful link? which one you are using . Thanks.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: Many many thanks for your comment. I followed this once but it does not work on latest version like marshmallow and other few devices. and may be google is recommending to use play service api also.

Comment: yes for marshmallow you have to add permission at run time, only menifest permission is not enough, as location permission comes under dangerous permission, go through this URL,  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html